# Should we return a HTTP 404 or 400 for a customer record that doesn't exist?

Tags: rest, http

I am creating a service to get the total yearly expenditure of a customer. The service input is the customer ID. If a customer that does not exist is received at the service, should a 404 (Not found) be thrown back to the consumer or should it be a 400 (Bad Request)?

Answer (score 3):

404.

Or a little longer: be as specific as you can. As you have alreay written yourself, a 404 is "not found", and the reason for the error is, that the customer cannot be found.

Only fall back to 400 if nothing else fits.

Comment: Thanks. I am in agreement with you. I was trying to be in alignment with the RFC description of 404 which says that "The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource" and based my thought of using 404 for this situation. Thank you for confirming.

Comment: 400 series codes indicate a problem with the request.  The request is valid.and should return an appropriate valid result with no data. Your framework should set the appropriate response code for you.

Comment: The 404 means page/endpoint not found. All 400-499 errors mean the client/caller made some mistakes (in the case of 404 - the client is trying to hit an endpoint which does not exist). 

If the record is not found then it should simply return 200 with empty data.

Answer (score 2):

If it’s a bad request, the caller should not have made the request. How is the caller supposed to know the customer Id doesn’t exist and not make the request? They can’t. So it’s not a bad request.

Customer not found therefore return status 404 not found.

Unless you have a request that returns a list of 0, 1 or more results. Then any number of results should return status 200.

(The important point is: 400 means the client should change their code. 400 isn’t something the client should “handle” at runtime except in the sense that “things went wrong”).